# Best fit circle with fix center in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I have a few points circle is passing through and I want to find the radius of the best fitting circle with center fixed at the origin.

CircFit doesn't allow specifying the center explicitly and I need it fixed at origin.

Comment: I have simply tried using CircFit and it doesn't allow me to fix a center. Is there any other function available in MATLAB which will allow me to do this?

Comment: A simple solution would be to take the average distance to each point from the center to approximate the circle's radius. What do you mean by best fit?

Comment: There is an error function which is the square of distance between the given points and the corresponding nearest points on the circle. I need to minimize the error and get the radius which does it.

Comment: The solution to the least squares optimization is the average distance of each point.

Comment: I know. It will include finding the nearest point on the circle and then calculating the distance. Gradient Descent can be used to minimize the function. I wanted to know if there is a function in MATLAB which can do it.

Comment: In MATLAB you could do it with `r = mean(sqrt((x - xc).^2 + (y - yc).^2))`

Comment: This is the distance from the point to the center. Not the distance from point to the nearest point on circle.

Comment: If you minimize the function `err = sum((sqrt((x-xc).^2 + (y-yc).^2) - r).^2)` with respect to `r`. You take the derivative of `err` with respect to `r` and set it to zero then solve for `r`. The solution you get to the minimization is `r = mean(sqrt((x - xc).^2 + (y - yc).^2))`. There's no need for gradient descent or anything like that.

Comment: I believe this is correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post my answer from the comments.

The distance from a point to the nearest point on a circle is `sqrt((x-xc).^2 + (y-yc).^2) - r).^2`. The error function for the least squares optimal is then `err = sum((sqrt((x-xc).^2 + (y-yc).^2) - r).^2)`.

Taking the derivative of `err` with respect to `r` and setting it to zero, then solving for `r` gives you the solution `r = mean(sqrt((x - xc).^2 + (y - yc).^2))`.

As a MATLAB function this could be written as

```
function r = circfitFixedC(x,y,xc,xy)
    r = mean(sqrt((x - xc).^2 + (y - xy).^2));
```